# Laravel Eloquent: Join two models using just one SQL query (using JOIN)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have two models. There are just two different tables, and the only common is the order number.

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'OrderId';
    protected $keyType = 'string';

    protected $table = 'Order';

    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function crmOrder()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(CrmOrder::class, 'Order_Num', 'OrderId')
            ->select(['Account', 'OrderType']);
    }
}

class CrmOrder extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'Order_Num';
    protected $keyType = 'string';

    protected $table = 'CRMORDERS';

    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;
}
```

When I'm trying to query the following.

```
Order::with('crmOrder')->select(['OrderId', 'OrderCreatedDt'])->whereDate('OrderCreatedDt', '>', DB::raw('DATEADD(day,-21,GETDATE())'))->get();
```

I see two different queries. 1st is to model Order and 2nd to CrmOrder with ids from the 1st result. How to make just one query using JOIN between them?

Comment: Your example query is perfect for laravel, what are you not achieving or looking for?

Comment: @kgtu your database is prepared for the disaster. As a user mentioned, you are using PascalCase and snake_case... you should be using snake_case as the documentation states...

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: corrected to table names.

```
$orders = Orders::join('CRMORDERS', 'order.OrderId', '=', 'CRMORDERS.Order_Num')->get(['orders.*', 'CRMORDERS.*']);
```

Comment: It would be better to use Models and let the relationships automatically do the right query

Comment: @matiaslauriti yeah I know. no idea why their asking this but they have already done it the right way. But then again they are also mixing camel case with snake case & pascal case. could be to speed up queries since its just one verse the eloquent 2.

Comment: There is an error:  Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'crmOrder'. (SQL: select [order].*, [crmOrder].* from [order] inner join [crmOrder] on [order].[OrderId] = [crmOrder].[Order_Num])'

Comment: I think join asks table name - not a model

Comment: Looks like it ignores $table from the first model and passes model name... so real sql join available only using table names in builder, i can't use models for join?..